# Pagination Item returns undefined after a few clicks

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-bootstrap

I have an application page that returns data from an api and renders the data. The data is limited to 20 records per page. I am trying to add pagination, and pagination page items seem to work fine. If you click on a page, the offset is adjusted according to page requested, data re-fetched and rendered.
I have now added a previous and first page item to pagination, which seem to work at first, but after several clicks on other page items, the click just returns undefined.

Below the code for the main page:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo, useCallback } from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import { withAuthenticator, Loading } from 'aws-amplify-react'
import request from "../utilities/request"
import SEO from "../components/seo"
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table'
import { currLocale, formatDate } from '../utilities/formatting'
import BasicPagination from '../components/pagination'



const ProductionOrders = (props) => {
  const [offset,setOffset] = useState(0)
  let records = 20
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState({})
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [activePage, setActivePage] = useState(0)
  const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState()

  const handlePrev = (e) => {
    console.log(activePage)
    if (activePage <=1) {return}
    setOffset(offset-records)
  }
  
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.persist()
    console.log(e.target.attributes.value)
    const pageRequested = parseInt(e.target.attributes.value.value)
    console.log(`pageRequested${pageRequested}`)
    if (pageRequested =='prev') {
      setActivePage(activePage-1) 
      return }
    if (pageRequested === activePage) {return}
    setOffset((pageRequested-1)*records)
    console.log(e.target.attributes.value.value)
    console.log(offset)
  }

  function isEmpty(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchOrders() {
      const url = `${process.env.ERP_API_URL}/production-orders?offset=${offset}&records=${records}`
      const response = await request(url)
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
      setIsLoading(false)
      if (response === undefined) { return }
      console.log(response)
      const body = response.body
      if (!body) { return }
      setActivePage((offset/records)+1)
      setOrders(JSON.parse(body))
      

      
      console.log(orders)

    }

    fetchOrders()

  }, [offset])

 useEffect(() => {
  if (isEmpty(orders)) {return }
  setTotalPages(orders[0].recordCount)
 },[orders])

/* const totalPages = useMemo(() => {
  console.log(`TotalPages:${orders[0].recordCount}`)
  if (isEmpty(orders)) { return }
  return (orders[0].recordCount)
},[orders]) */

  return (
    <>
      <SEO title="Ürün Detay" />
      {((!isLoading) & (!isEmpty(orders))) ? (
        <Container>
          <h1>Üretim Emirleri</h1>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Tarih</th>
                    <th>Fiş No</th>
                    <th>Ürün Kodu</th>
                    <th>Ürün Adı</th>
                    <th>Varyant Kodu</th>
                    <th>Varyant Adı</th>
                    <th>Planlanan Miktar</th>
                    <th>Üretilen Miktar</th>
                    <th>Durum</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {orders.map(order => (
                    <tr key={order.prodOrderId}>
                      <td>{formatDate(order.createdOn)}</td>
                      <td>{order.prodOrderNumber}</td>
                  <td><Link to={`/app/item-details/${order.product[0].id}`}>{order.product[0].code}</Link></td>
                  <td className="text-truncate" style={{maxWidth:'90px'}}>{order.product[0].name}</td>
                  {order.product[0].hasOwnProperty('variantCode') ? <td>{order.product[0].variantCode}</td> : <td></td>}
                  {order.product[0].hasOwnProperty('variantName') ? <td className="text-truncate" style={{maxWidth:'30px'}}>{order.product[0].variantName}</td> : <td></td>}
                  <td>{order.plannedQuantity}</td>
                  <td>{order.producedQuantity}</td>
                  <td>{order.prodOrderStatus}</td>
          
                    </tr>


                  ))}

                </tbody>


              </Table>
              <BasicPagination totalPages={Math.ceil(totalPages/records)} active={activePage} callBack={handleClick} prev={handlePrev}/>
            </Col>
          </Row>

        </Container>
      )
        : (!isLoading ? (<p>An error has occurred</p>) : (<p>Still Loading</p>))
      }
    </>
  )
}
export default withAuthenticator(ProductionOrders)
```

And this is the code for pagination:

```
import React from 'React'
import { Prev } from 'react-bootstrap/esm/PageItem'
import Pagination from 'react-bootstrap/Pagination'

const BasicPagination = (props) => {
    let items = []
    const pages = props.totalPages
    for (let i = 1; i <= props.totalPages; i++) {
        items.push(
            <Pagination.Item key={i} active={i === props.active} value={i} name="page" onClick={(e) => props.callBack(e)}>
                {i}
            </Pagination.Item>
        )
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Pagination>
                <Pagination.First value={1} onClick={(e) => props.callBack(e)} />
                <Pagination.Prev onClick={(e) => props.prev(e)} />
                {items}
                <Pagination.Last value={pages} onClick={(e) => props.callBack(e)} />
            </Pagination>
        </>
    )
}

export default BasicPagination
```

1. Why do I have problems after several clicks?
2. Is there a better way to access event data? Instead of `e.target.attributes.value.value`

Comment: are you able to reproduce this in http://codesandbox.io/?

Answer (score 1):

Passing the event object onClick was the problem. I solved the problem by simply passing selected number like so:

````
for (let i = 1; i <= props.totalPages; i++) {
        items.push(
            <Pagination.Item key={i} active={i === props.active} value={i} name="page" onClick={() => props.callBack(i)}>
                {i}
            </Pagination.Item>
        )
    }```
````